# Is it possible to allow toast notifications but hide them from the action center?

Tags: 8.1, notifications, action-center

The short line is this: Some apps I don't bother lost the *notification* since a lost the *toast*. I don't want it in the *action center*.

A good example is a auto checkin app that ask me to do its job in a *toast notification*.
In case I miss the toast and see this 30 minutes after in the **action center**. I'm not in the same place, it worthless.

Another good examples are *notifications* from phone and messages. Since I already use it in the *lock screen*, + in the *Nokia Glance* + the number in tile I really don't need it in the **action center**, just the tile (and the *toast* in the case of messages).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is **not** possible from the settings in current version of the system.

I think this option is left for the developers - they now have API for manipulation with own action center items, so they *may implement* such behavior *if* it is *appropriate*.

This will come with time as more developers will made updates for their apps and start to manage their notifications in better ways for new system.

Other example would be multiple notifications about one particular event which is currently generating multiple notification items - myBattery and its 20%,19%,18%,17% (well,you get the point). In this case I care about only one item and that would be the last one. This is another task for developers as they can delete notification item if the new one should replace the old one.

---

EDIT:

Extract from WPCentral [article on action center](http://www.wpcentral.com/app-windows-phone-81-can-display-20-notifications-action-center) (**the bold lines are relevant to your question**):

### Consumer features

- 20 Notifications per app
- Persistent notifications for 7 days (or shorter)
- Users can “chase” (tap) a notification
- Users can remove a notification
- Users can remove a group of notifications
- Users can remove all notifications
- Action Center is only available on phones

### Action Center Management APIs

- Manage app notifications
- **Developers can remove one or many notifications**
- Developers can tag and group notifications
- Developers can replace a notification with a new one
- **Developers can set an expiration on notifications**
- Developers can send “Ghost Toast” notifications

And what is *Ghost Toast*?

> An app can send you a notification without turning your display on or alerting you if it’s not that important. An example of that would be an update about gaining a new follower or friend request on a social network. It’s something you can attend to later and don’t need to divert your attention towards right away. It’ll still show up in the Action Center, but only when you purposefully go there.

Comment: So developers now can show toasts and avoit themselves to show it in action center?

Comment: @VitorCanova Yes that's right. I didn't play with that API myself, but I think it will be possible. I edited the answer to mention what exactly is possible.

Comment: Wow, that was such a great answer. thanks.